# Is there a way to parse the "safelinks" URL from outlook in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have an "Editor" that allows users to compose emails in a WPF window. However, when there's an incoming email which has "Urls", Microsoft (outlook) obfuscates it by adding some extra characters along with "nam01.safelinks" stuff. Is there a way I can parse it in my code to present it with an "hyperlink"?

Example: 
http://www.google.com will be transformed into something like: 
https://nam01.safelinks.protection.outlook.com?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%[some_id]%7C1&data=%3D&reserved=0

Comment: This is an official security feature of office. How about you fix the problem, rather then trying to ignore the detection? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/office-365-security/office-365-atp?view=o365-worldwide

Comment: @Christopher: When you say "fix the problem", what do you mean?

Comment: *Something* about the link must be tripping up the protection. Chances are, it is actually feigning to be a normal google link via the text. Otherwise, it might be the lack of HTTPS causing the protection to be too agressive. And of course, as any feature it can be turned off if it is genuinely bugged and patches do not fix that.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work this way:

```
string s = "https://nam01.safelinks.protection.outlook.com?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&data=%3D&reserved=0";

Uri u = new Uri( s );

var n = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString( u.Query );

string url = n["url"];
```

Got it from this:[MSDN Forums](http://%20https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ec21adb9-6990-4dba-be0b-c33b97afbbfb/is-there-a-way-to-parse-the-8220safelinks8221-url-from-outlook-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral)